Nginx config for Kubernetes Backend frontend service
I have an app with a backend and frontend, and I would like to deploy it to Kubernetes,
I deployed the backend as deployment,
and for the front end, I used the nginx image to also write the nginx config.
The backend exposes this APIs:
GET /apps
POST /apps
PUT /apps
DELETE /apps

and the frontend is created by nextjs, and router is:
/apps
/new
/edit

I used this nginx config:
upstream backend {
    server myapp-backend.myapp:8080;
}
server {

listen 80;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location /api/  {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}

}


but when i access the app in browser the frontend can't call the backend,
and when i try GET /api/apps it 404.
I tried also with regexp:
location ~ ^/api(/?)(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://backend/$2;
}

but didn't work either, it was redirected to /apps (frontend)
Therefore, what I actually need is an nginx config that tells the location /api to use the proxy_pass,
but with removing /api from URI cause the API endpoints does't have this path, (that's why it returned 404 in the first option.)
I tried, but it doesn't work
location ~ ^/api(/?)(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://backend/$2;
}

neither of this is working
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}

